# Need query to start at the beginning of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    ATB.AcountCountDesc,
    TB.LastFirstName,
    N.EMAIL,
    TB.AccountNumber,
    TB.OpenShareCount,
    TB.MemberOpenDate,
    TB.OpenMemberCount,
    TB.OpenShareBalance,
    SH.ShareType,
    FORMAT(SH.ShareOpenDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "ShareOpenDate",
    SH.ShareCreatedByUser,
    SH.ShareCreatedByUserName,
    SH.ShareBranchName,
    SH.ShareBranch,
    cast(month(SH.ShareOpenDate) as varchar) + '/' + cast(year(SH.ShareOpenDate) as varchar) as 'Open Period',
    CONCAT(SH.ShareCreatedByUser, '-',SH.ShareCreatedByUserName) 'Opened By'
FROM
    arcu.vwARCUOperationMemberTrialBalance as TB
    INNER JOIN arcu.vwARCUOperationMemberAccountTrialBalance as ATB ON TB.MemberSuppID = ATB.MemberID
    and TB.ProcessDate = ATB.PDate
    and TB.MemberStatus = 0 -- Account count for open Members only
    and TB.AccountStatus <> 1
    INNER JOIN arcu.vwARCUShare AS SH ON TB.ProcessDate = SH.ProcessDate
    AND TB.AccountNumber = SH.AccountNumber
    INNER JOIN NAME AS N ON TB.AccountNumber = N.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE
    ATB.AcountCountDesc = 1
    AND TB.OpenShareCount >= 1
    AND SH.ShareType = '00'
    AND SH.ShareID != '40'
    AND SH.ShareOpenDate >= DATEADD(s, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), -2))
    AND TB.MemberOpenDate = SH.ShareOpenDate
    AND N.EMAIL <> ''
    AND N.EMAIL is not null
order by MemberOpenDate Desc;
```

Issue: the MemberOpen Date starts on 08/02/2021.
Desired outcome: I need it to start on 08/01/2021
What I have tried: I have tried declaring a variable and calculating the start of the month by using datediff and still get the 08/02/2021 outcome.
I tried changing the => to = or <= and the issue persists. Please help.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desires results as formatted text.

Comment: Formatting your SQL is also a must; *good* use of white space and line breaks in any language is very important.

Comment: It was formatted...when I paste into the stackoverflow it goes everywhere and I tried to organize it as much as I could trying to use the buttons on top.

Comment: @Dale K the data in the column as explained looks like: MemberOpenDate and it starts at 08/11/2021 and ends in 08/02/2021. Ordered by MemberOpenDate Desc.

Comment: We need a [mre] not just one date.

Comment: And what is the datatype of the columns you are storing these dates in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the 1st of the month using `EOMONTH` something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ATB.AcountCountDesc,TB.LastFirstName,N.EMAIL,TB.AccountNumber,TB.OpenShareCount,TB.MemberOpenDate,
        TB.OpenMemberCount,TB.OpenShareBalance,SH.ShareType,FORMAT(SH.ShareOpenDate,'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "ShareOpenDate",
        SH.ShareCreatedByUser,SH.ShareCreatedByUserName,SH.ShareBranchName,SH.ShareBranch,cast(month(SH.ShareOpenDate) 
        as varchar) + '/' + cast(year(SH.ShareOpenDate) as varchar)as 'Open Period', CONCAT(SH.ShareCreatedByUser,'-',SH.ShareCreatedByUserName)
        'Opened By'
FROM arcu.vwARCUOperationMemberTrialBalance as TB
     JOIN arcu.vwARCUOperationMemberAccountTrialBalance as ATB
                ON TB.MemberSuppID = ATB.MemberID
                and TB.ProcessDate = ATB.PDate
                and TB.MemberStatus = 0 -- Account count for open Members only
                and TB.AccountStatus <> 1
     JOIN arcu.vwARCUShare AS SH
                ON TB.ProcessDate = SH.ProcessDate
                AND TB.AccountNumber = SH.AccountNumber 
     JOIN NAME AS N ON TB.AccountNumber = N.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE
    ATB.AcountCountDesc = 1 AND 
    TB.OpenShareCount >= 1 AND
    SH.ShareType = '00' AND
    SH.ShareID  !='40' AND
    SH.ShareOpenDate >= (select dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(month, -1, eomonth(getdate()))))  AND
    TB.MemberOpenDate = SH.ShareOpenDate AND
    N.EMAIL <> '' AND
    N.EMAIL is not null
order by MemberOpenDate Desc;
```

Comment: I just tried that SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS and the column still starts with a 08/02/2021

Comment: When I run just that function it returns '2021-08-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Does the table contain rows with datetimes on the 1st of Aug?

Comment: Yes, it does contain data on that day

Comment: Even If I tried the following queries, I still get 08/02/2021 on the output.                                                            SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), -1) 
select dateadd(mm, -1,dateadd(dd, -1, eomonth(getdate())))

Comment: Please try this: select dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(month, -1, eomonth(getdate())))

Comment: @CarlosDiaz De nada

Comment: @CarlosDiaz I updated the code.  If it was helpful please mark as answer